# What font is used in this "Create an online store" image from Shopify?

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone name this font?

[image]

source: http://www.shopify.com

Comment: **To find a font from a picture:** http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Myriad Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/myriad/)

[image]

..................

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately the price of the font is high. Would you know of a free alternative that would look close to it?

Comment: @tucson A truetype version of Myriad Web Pro Bold (a web-hinted and optimized version of Myriad Pro) is [available at the Adobe Store](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1507) as part of a 12-font bundle for a very reasonable $69. Myriad Pro Regular, Bold, Italic and Bold Italic are bundled with Adobe Reader 7 and 8.  In Adobe Reader 9 and onwards, the fonts are included, but not installed in the system fonts directory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what font it is but all the similarity goes with **MYRIAD Pro BOLD** & i think you also want to  know the effects which are applied so i am attaching a SS.
[image: Screen shot]
You can change its gradient to  white color `#ffffff` in place of `#eeeeee` (used in example)

Hope this will help.